# Как получить все реакции с поста в VK API?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, requests

Есть небольшие затруднения с получением фидбэка от аудитории с постов в вк. Моя задача - узнать кол-во реакций на посте типа "Ого!", "Восторг", "Печаль" и тп при помощи библиотеки requests в python. В справочнике API я обнаружил только Likes.getList, который, мне кажется, выводит только отметки "Мне нравится", то есть банальные сердечки. Подскажите, как мне вывести кол-во каждой из этих реакций по отдельности?